# RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'src' not found while handling absolute import - AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am having trouble with a simple Python Lambda Function. The Lambda (called by Zapier) function basically creates a Confluence Page and recalls another Zapier Webhook. I upload a .zip file in my S3, which has all folders of the required packages, and then a **src** folder with my Python file which has my handler function.

.zip --> src/lambda_function.py which then I call a handler function.

At the top of my lambda_function.py I have the following:

```
import string
import json
import pyconfluence as pyco
import requests
import os
import time

def create_page(name, content, label):
    data = {}
    data["type"] = "page"
    data["title"] = name
    data["ancestors"] = [{"id": str(12345678)}] #172949526 is the Parent
    data["space"] = {"key": "PK"}
    data["body"] = {"storage": {"value": content, "representation": "storage"}}
    data["metadata"] = {"labels": [{"name": label}]}
    return pyco.api.rest("/", "POST", json.dumps(data))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Page 12345678 that is in fact a representation of the template
    content = pyco.get_page_content(12345678)
    page_title = event['issue_key'] + ": " + event['issue_title']
    content = string.replace(content, "PK-200", event['issue_key'])  
    create_page(page_title, content, "active-product-requirement")
    api_url = "https://acmein.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"+event['issue_key']+"/remotelink/"

    webhook = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/123456/8v6fde/'

    requisite_headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    auth = (os.environ["PYCONFLUENCE_USER"], os.environ["PYCONFLUENCE_TOKEN"])
    result = requests.get(api_url, headers=requisite_headers, auth=auth).json()

    if len(result) > 0:
        confluence_url = result[0]["object"]["url"]
    else:
        confluence_url = "Error getting the page"
    callback = requests.post(webhook, data={'issue_key': event['issue_key'], 'confluence_url': confluence_url })
    return ["Success"]
```

and then in my CloudWatch logs I have the following errors:

[image]

Comment: If you want help with a problem in your code, you need to show us the code. You're asking us to guess what you have written and then tell you what you should have written.

Answer (score 0):

You have to zip the **contents** of the `src` folder, not the `src` folder itself. Your python module (`lambda_function.py`) should be at the first level in you zip.
See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html):

> Zip the directory content, not the directory. The contents of the Zip file are available as the current working directory of the Lambda function.